# What is <meta> in html and how it can be useful?

Tags: html, meta

I don't know what is *meta* element in HTML and its usability. What is the purpose of *name* and *content* attributes, and how will this element affect my webpage?

I have seen it a couple of times and I tried to learn from a book, but I couldn't understand it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>What is meta?</title>
    <meta>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Meta is another word for self-referential, which means that meta(data) tags provide information about the HTML document (i.e. the webpage) itself.

[w3schools has a good description on the HTML `meta` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp):

> They won't be displayed on the page, but will be machine parsable.

For example, common meta tag attributes are `description` (what is this document about?) and `author` (who does this belong to?) which are used for machines like search engines.

Beyond this, you can also set things like character encoding and the `viewport` which is commonly used for responsive web design, so you can probably guess that it can be widely useful for your webpage!

Good luck in your learning.

Other resources:

- https://smallbusiness.chron.com/meta-tags-used-promote-accessibility-search-engine-opimization-74918.html
- https://metatags.io
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Answer (score 0):

It helps at bit with your site's seo and makes it easier for search engines to know more about your site. Some tags, however, can be viewed in the search engine (eg. `description` can be seen in Google under the link)